# DocumentFile.createDirectory() which will be writable as File object

Tags: android, realm, android-permissions, android-sdcard, android-memory

I have some paths on sd card on Android 7, which are unwritable using instant access requiring, so I have to use StorageVolume.createAccessIntent and therefore use DocumentFile later instead of File. But the problem is that I need to use File, because db lib(realm), that I'm using, simply uses File object to store data. So the point is that I have to createDirectory and this directory(it's path) has to have writing access. How to do this using DocumentFile.createDirectory() or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the point is that I have to createDirectory and this directory(it's path) has to have writing access

That is not supported.

The only direct filesystem access that you have to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) is via `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()` (all methods on `Context`). If these return 2+ items, the second and subsequent ones are locations on removable storage that are unique to your app and which you can read/write using classic `File` objects.

Otherwise, keep your Realm database on [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), then copy it to removable storage at some appropriate point (e.g., user-initiated "export" or "backup" operation).